# Will my regex catch all color values?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, colors

I wrote a regex to validify color values. It should take 3 digit hexadecimals, 6 digits hexadecimals, and rgb values in the form rgb(111,111,111), where the numbers are anything up to 255. Here it is:

```
^(\#([1-9a-fA-F]{3}|[1-9a-fA-F]{6})|[rR][gG][bB]\(([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|(2[1234]\d|5[012345]))\,([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|(2[1234]\d|5[012345]))\,([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|(2[1234]\d|5[012345]))\))$
```

I know it's a bit long and inefficient, but that's not the point. What I'm wondering is this: Will it be able to catch all inputs from an html input of the type color? I'm testing on internet explorer, so the color input just shows up as a text box. However, I know that certain browsers use a fancy-looking color selection tool in place of the text box for color inputs, and I'm wondering if this regex will catch the inputs that they create, and if not, how I can make it do so.

Comment: No idea, but you might look into the `i` flag.

Comment: I take my "no idea" back: No, it won't. There are also `rgba(r, g, b, a)` values.

Comment: Do you have to use a regexp? You're most of the time better off using a series of simpler regexps and also plain old string splitting/matching. You must have expended a lot of mental energy writing that regexp. Folks reading your question in order to help are expending a lot of additional mental energy trying to parse the regexp. It just may not be worth all this effort.

Comment: Isn't easy search for `color` and take its value? Like `/color\s*:\s*([^'";]+)/g`

Comment: What about colors written using their English name like `black`?